# .NET Azure functions auto create subscriber

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, masstransit

in my application, I use mass transit, which takes care of creating topics, subscriptions, and queues. Now, I have an Azure function, and I would like to use "objects" instead of directly referencing the queue and subscription names. Ideally, I would like the subscription to be created automatically. Is this possible? I was thinking of adding mass transit, but I am not sure if it's a good idea. However, if I need to send messages from the function to the message broker, I would still like to have mass transit there.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is unfortunately not possible since dynamic names for queues and subscriptions will not allow the function app to scale out when required.

But what you can do is to leverage [chaining of entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) in service bus to make this dynamic.

You would listen to just one queue and, as required, forward requests from other queues or subscriptions to this queue.